# JavaScript reference drop

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a module that extends existing application. I've received a variable `device` and I want to create `myDevice` that will **always** hold the same data. Lets say that data is contained in an array:

https://jsfiddle.net/hmkg9q60/2/

```js
var device = {
  name: "one",
  data: [1, 2, 3]
};
var myDevice = {
  name: "two",
  data: []
};

myDevice.data = device.data; // Assign array reference


device.data.push(4); // Push works on array reference

console.log(device.data); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(myDevice.data); // [1, 2, 3, 4] - ok


device.data = [0, 0, 0]; // A new array is assigned to 'device'
// and 'myDevice' reference stays with old array

console.log(device.data); // [0, 0, 0] 
console.log(myDevice.data); // [1, 2, 3, 4] - I would like to get [0,0,0]
```

What I would like to obtain is to be sure, that `myDevice` will always hold the same data as `device`, even if someone decides to use the assign operator somewhere in the application. I don't want to clone `myDevice` because I want to hold "name" and other properties.

Is there a way in JavaScript to create such reference to an object field?

Comment: You could use a getter: `myDevice.getData = () => device.data;`

Comment: Maybe even change the data.toString()

Comment: Thank you, I can apply this solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use getters and setters, and read and assign directly from and to the `device` object.

```js
var device = {
  name: "one",
  data: [1, 2, 3]
};
var myDevice = {
  name: "two",
  get data() { return device.data; },
  set data(newdata) { device.data = newdata; },
};

console.log(myDevice.data);
device.data = [4,5,6];
console.log(myDevice.data);
```

Comment: Cool. I had not seen that before - even `console.log(myDevice);` works well

Comment: Thanks :D I wasn't sure the getter and setter could have the same name, but they can! So that made things easier

Answer (score 3):

I would use a getter

**NOTE:** [more elegant ES6 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56542896/295783)

```js
var device = {
  name: "one",
  data: [1, 2, 3]
};
var myDevice = {}
myDevice.getData = () => device.data;
myDevice.bla = "bla";

device.data.push(4); // Push works on array reference

console.log(device.data); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(myDevice.getData()); // [1, 2, 3, 4] - ok


device.data = [0, 0, 0]; // A new array is assigned to 'device'
// and 'myDevice' reference stays with old array

console.log(device.data); // [0, 0, 0] 
console.log(myDevice.getData()); // [1, 2, 3, 4] - I would like to get [0,0,0]
```